# Use leaning of the phone to move your Character

Tags: ios, swift, cmmotionmanager

My goal is to move my character whenever the phone is leaned to the side. Kind of like it used to be in "DoodleJump". I have not found anything about it yet. Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: use the accelerometer and gyroscope or simply read through the docs and go from there https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CMMotionManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/index.html) for this purpose.

> A CMMotionManager object is the gateway to the motion services
>   provided by iOS. These services provide an app with accelerometer
>   data, rotation-rate data, magnetometer data, and other device-motion
>   data such as attitude. These types of data originate with a device’s
>   accelerometers and (on some models) its magnetometer and gyroscope.

Checkout [this](http://nshipster.com/cmdevicemotion/) `Swift` tutorial to get started.